# Is there a limit of fonts in the font-family?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

Is there a limit on the number of font names can be declared from the below style? The maximum I see is 4 but is it allowed to have more than 4?

```
body{
    font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

**Update:**

We tried up to 8 fonts and it is still working... Looks like there is no limit at all.

Comment: Of course it is, why should there be any such arbitrary limitation?

Comment: You may want to have a look at section 15.3.1 [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop)

Comment: @Mohan Wijesena: Where does that subsection suggest that there may be a limit?